# Show that $\frac{\sum^k_{i=1}\text{Var}(Y_i)}{\sum^p_{i=1}\text{Var}(X_i)}=\frac{\sum^k_{i=1}\lambda_i}{\sum^p_{i=1}\lambda_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, principal-component-analysis

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_p)$ be a random vector with $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu$ and covariance matrix $\text{Cov}(X)=\Sigma$. Define $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_p)^T=\mathbb{E}^TX$, where $E$ is a $p\times p$ matrix with columns equal to the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$. Show that $$\frac{\sum^k_{i=1}\text{Var}(Y_i)}{\sum^p_{i=1}\text{Var}(X_i)}=\frac{\sum^k_{i=1}\lambda_i}{\sum^p_{i=1}\lambda_i}$$

where $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_p$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.

Here is how I tackle the problem:

To show that $\sum^p_{i=1}\text{Var}(X_i)=\sum^p_{i=1}\lambda_i$:

We have that $$\sum^p_{i=1}\text{Var}(X_i)=Tr(Cov(X))=Tr(\Sigma)=Tr(E\Lambda E^T)=Tr(E^TE\Lambda)=Tr(\Lambda)=\sum^p_{i=1}\lambda_i$$

To show that $\sum^k_{i=1}\text{Var}(Y_i)=\sum^k_{i=1}\lambda_i$:

We have that $\text{Var}(Y_i)=\text{Var}(e_i^TX)=e_i^T\text{Cov}(X)e_i=e_i^T\Sigma e_i$.

So, $$\sum^k_{i=1}e_i^T\Sigma e_i=\sum^k_{i=1}e^T_iE\Lambda E^T e_i$$

We can see that $e_i^TE=s_i$, where $s_i$ is a p-dimensional row vector with entries 0 except for the $i$-th entry. This is because the columns of the matrix $E$ are orthonormal by definition. Furthermore, $E^Te_i=s_i^T$.

So, we have that $s_i\Lambda=l_i$, where $l_i$ is a p-dimension row vector, where the $i$-th entry is equal to $\lambda_i$. Hence, we get that $e_i^TE\Lambda E^Te_i=l_is_i^T=\lambda_i$.

Hence, we get that $\sum^k_{i=1}e_i^TE\Lambda E^Te_i=\sum^k_{i=1}\lambda_i$.

Would the way I approached this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems right to me.But let me give you this:

Let a a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$
where

- $n:$   the # of rows (observations)  and
- $p:$   the # of columns (variables)

$$S=P \Lambda P^{T}$$ , where $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors
$\Lambda$ the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues
$\lambda_{i}$ in decreasing order.The eigenvectors are the principal axis or the principal directions of the data (observations).

An orthogonal transformation of the standardized matrix  $\hat{X}$ is: $$\hat{Y} = \hat{X} P $$

From the above we can see that the matrix $P$ is the same as $U$ of the $\textbf{SVD}$ of the original $X$

We have 2 standardized matrices $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ where the $\textbf{SVD}$ of each matrix give us:

$$ \hat{X} = Q_{x} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma & 0\\ 0& 0\\  \end{bmatrix} P_{x}^{T} \: \: \: \: , \: \: \: \: \hat{Y} = Q_{y} \begin{bmatrix} \Psi & 0\\ 0& 0\\  \end{bmatrix} P_{y}^{T}  $$

Therefore the the PCA problem is now a problem of calculation of correlation these two matrices.We are searching a transformation matrix
$Α$ of the columns of of   $\hat{Y}$ such that : $$Ζ = \hat{Y}A.$$
The Variance - Covariance matrix of
$\hat{X},\hat{Y}$ is given by:
$$ Cor(X) = \dfrac{Z^{T}Z}{n-1}$$
Letting $$C = \Psi \hat{P}_{y}A$$gives us: $$Z = Q_{y} \begin{bmatrix}  \Psi \hat{P}_{y}A \\ 0 \\  \end{bmatrix}$$ such that  $Z^{T}Z = C^{T}C$

and therefore if the columns of $Z$ are orthonormal co is $C$

In addition the total variance is being explained from
$$\dfrac{ \lambda_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda } .$$